# Get Unique info from Pendrive C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, usb-drive, dongle

I want to get infos like PID, VID and SerialNumber from a Pendrive in C#, dotnet 6.

Im gonna use this to generate a dongle key.

I want to search this infos from a specific (letter, name etc.) pendrive, can't be the first or anything else, because maybe the user will have more than once pendrive plugged.

I've tried to use ManagementObjectSearcher.

`ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE (PNPClass = 'USB')`

But I can't search by the letter, or by the name of the pendrive.

So I need a way to list the pendrives and choose the pendrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so the annoying thing is that all the info you want actually come from 3 separate locations .

1. The USB DeviceId comes from `Win32_PnPEntity`
2. The drive Name/Model comes from `Win32_DiskDrive`
3. The drive Letter (e.g. `D:`) comes from `Win32_LogicalDisk`

These 3 queries are likely to give you the same number of results, representing the same drives, but giving you different pieces of the information:

```
var entities = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
  $"select * from Win32_PnPEntity where Service='USBSTOR'").Get();
var drives = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
  $"select * from Win32_DiskDrive where InterfaceType='USB'").Get();
var disks = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
  $"select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType='{(int)System.IO.DriveType.Removable}'").Get();
```

They are related, but their links are not the easiest to tease out. In this example, we will start from the Drive Letters, traversing the connections using [ASSOCIATORS OF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/associators-of-statement), through this path: `LogicalDisk -> DiskPartition -> DiskDrive -> PnPEntity`

```
foreach (ManagementObject disk in disks)
{
    var partition = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        $"associators of {{{disk.Path}}} where ResultClass=Win32_DiskPartition")
        .Get().OfType<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();

    var drive = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        $"associators of {{{partition?.Path}}} where ResultClass=Win32_DiskDrive")
        .Get().OfType<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();

    var entity = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        $"associators of {{{drive?.Path}}} where ResultClass=Win32_PnPEntity")
        .Get().OfType<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine($"""
        Letter='{disk["DeviceID"]}'
        Model='{drive?["Model"]}'
        Serial='{drive?["SerialNumber"]}'
        ID='{entity?["DeviceId"]}'
        -----
        """);
}
```

Which, on my system with one USB stick conected, returns:

```
Letter='E:'
Model='SanDisk 3.2Gen1 USB Device'
Serial='123456789'
ID='USBSTOR\DISK&VEN__USB&PROD__SANDISK_3.2GEN1&REV_1.00\123456789&0'
```

Of course, you have the possibility of using an un-formatted drive. In which case, you will neither have a `Partition` nor a `LogicalDrive`. In which case, you may want to start from `DiskDrive`, and traverse the associations from there.